# How to return None?

Tags: python, return, nonetype

```
def where_is_waldo(names):

    if "Waldo" in names:
        return names.index("Waldo")
    else:
        return None
```

```
where_is_waldo(["Peter", "Waldo", "John"])
```

returns 1, but why does

```
where_is_waldo(["Peter", "John"])
```

not return `None`? It returns simply nothing...
I know that
`print(where_is_waldo(["Peter", "John"]))`
would return `None` but I'm curious how to do it without the `print` statement

Comment: Returning None is displayed as returning nothing by the REPL. What your print does is _printing_ None, that's different from _returning_ None.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, it should be pointed out, this is a feature that is special-cased by the REPL specifically

Answer (score 3):

It does return None.

```
def where_is_waldo(names):
    if "Waldo" in names:
        return names.index("Waldo")
    else:
        return None
        
listNames = ["Peter", "John"]
index = where_is_waldo(listNames)
if index is None:
    print("Waldo is not present")
else:
    print("Waldo is present at index ", index)
```

Output:

```
Waldo is not present
```

Update: Thanks to Matthias's suggestion for changing `index == None` to `index is None`.

Answer (score 1):

When you return `None`, there's literally None to display because of the implementation of `__repr__` in the `None` object. So, you'll get nothing to display.

Comment: "there is literally None to display" no, not really. This is a feature of the REPL, but `print(None)` prints `None`